# Dynamically rendered images in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm working on the blog based on React, TS and Gatsby.

Blog posts are based on markdown. Each blog post will have a similar header with title, time necessary to read the article and the logos of the technologies that the particular blog post will be about.

I have a problem with rendering those images dynamically. My idea was to create something like this in markdown

```
---
path: "/fourth"
date: "2021-06-02"
title: "TypeScript - intro"
readTime: "140"
author: "Adam Kniec"
imgs: [typescript, react]
---

That's the fourth blog post
```

after that I wanted to create a graphql query and get the imgs names like so:

```
export const postQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostByPath($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
    path
    readTime
    title
    author
    imgs
    date
  }
}
```

}
`;

I have the array of images in the props now and I wanted to render those images like this

```
{data.markdownRemark.frontmatter.imgs.map((imgPath) => {
          const imgPatha = `../images/${imgPath}`;

          return <StaticImage src={imgPatha} alt="asdasd" />;
        })}
```

Unfortunately, gatsby gives me the warning

> react_devtools_backend.js:2560 Image not loaded ../images/typescript

Is this the correct approach ? Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or how to render those images dynamically.

Comment: [Check out the restrictions in the docs here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image#restrictions-on-using-staticimage). In short, you cannot use props to determine the path for `StaticImage` because it is a hack that uses static analysis to determine the reference.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Would using the Img from gatsby-imagrg be the good choice to achieve dynamically rendered images ?

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said by [@coreyward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203130/coreyward) you can't use dynamic `props` in the `StaticImage` component, it's a known restriction.

That said, you have two choices:

- Using the standard `img` HTML tag.
- Using the `GatsbyImage` component. To do it, you'll need to add the images in your filesystem to allow Gatsby to create the proper nodes and then, you will need to query them in your pages/templates. Without further details on the implementation, it's impossible to guess how your code should look like but the idea relies on something like:

  ```
  import { graphql } from "gatsby"
  import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

  function BlogPost({ data }) {
    const image = getImage(data.blogPost.avatar)
    return (
      <section>
        <h2>{data.blogPost.title}</h2>
        <GatsbyImage image={image} alt={data.blogPost.author} />
        <p>{data.blogPost.body}</p>
      </section>
    )
  }

  export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query {
      blogPost(id: { eq: $Id }) {
        title
        body
        author
        avatar {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(
              width: 200
              placeholder: BLURRED
              formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
            )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
  ```